# In workflow 'Set content approval status' do not change approval status

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, content-approval

I have manual workflow, where I want to set content approval status to 'Approved'. I use Set content approval status action.

It is executing, but it do not change my workflow.

*More info:*
I also have 2 other workflows started on change/edit.

**How do I use that action?**

Comment: set the workflow to wait for the status field to change.

Comment: Now I have workflow that waits 4th minute... endless loop.  Changing state is literarly last step in my workflow. It just does not work at all.

Comment: you do trigger your wf manually or does it trigger on some action?